# Program which stay in memory and I want to access data from other program code

Tags: winforms, vb6

I want to write a program in .NET (c#), this will run the memory (a formless/hidden form windows app). From another .net and VB6 application code I need to access the data stored in this program. How can I do this?

Any idea? I can make .net program as COM visible to make it accessible from VB code. But whenever I create an instance of this program to access from code I'll loose the data stored in this.

How do I  overcome this?

Comment: This can be an exe which is running in the background, from other programs I need to access the data stored in this exe.

Comment: You need to keep your reference to the program until you no longer want it. Here's how someone did it with a recordset object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234086/xl-add-in-vba-and-persistent-objects You need to do the same type of thing. OR have your net program save it's state on disconnect and load it again when initialised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can make .net program as COM visible to make it accessible from VB code

That doesn't do what you hope it does.  Works fine at runtime, but you'll actually load the EXE as an in-process server.  Just like a DLL.  The CLR doesn't pay attention to the filename extension of a .NET assembly, only the display name.  Everything seems to work just fine but of course you can't get the correct data.

Creating out-of-process servers in .NET is a pretty awkward affair.  Only COM+ hosting is supported, you need to derive your visible classes from [ServicedComponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.servicedcomponent.aspx).  The how-to MSDN articles [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x7357ez%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Consider using the standard .NET process interop support instead.  Take your pick from sockets, named pipes or WCF.

Comment: thank you so much for your comments, I'm looking at serviced component.